What is the IMDb Title of this Chinese movie about Yang Yuhuan?
This movie was telecast on Sri Lanka Rupavahini Corporation (SLRC). The story of the movie deals with Yang Yuhuan. I like this movie very much. All the actors performed well. I found a movie clip of this movie at YouTube. According to the description:

This movie is producted in 1992 [...] The primary actor is Zhou Jie, who is the best dancer in china.

Click here to go to  the address:
I don’t know the original title of the movie. I could not find the IMDb entry of this movie. Please provide the title of the movie.

The name of that movie is actually the first three Chinese characters in the video title: 杨贵妃 (Yang GuiFei), also listed in some places as Imperial Concubine Yang (贵妃 means [imperial] concubine). Yang GuiFei is the name she becomes better known as later in life. 
It's doesn't seem to have an IMDb listing at all. 
Here's a page with the movie listing and description (in Chinese):   http://baike.baidu.com/subview/6644/7992124.htm
And here's one with sparser details in English:
http://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/5456376
Looks like most details on this movie are in Chinese.
